# replacing a text by an image in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

That's my code :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendChatMessage(string msg, int ToClient)
{
    if (msg != null && ToClient != 0)
    {
        if (msg.Contains(":-)")) msg.Replace(":-)", "<img src='Styles/emojie/smile.png'   />  ");
        else if (msg.Contains(":-(")) msg.Replace(":-(", "<img src='Styles/emojie/sad.png'   />  ");
        else if (msg.Contains(":'-(")) msg.Replace(":'-(", "<img src='Styles/emojie/cry.png'   />  ");
        else if (msg.Contains(":-$")) msg.Replace(":-$", "<img src='Styles/emojie/shy.png'   />  ");
        int FromClientID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["ClientID"]);
        string query = "insert into chat (FROM_CLIENT,TO_CLIENT,CHAT_MSG) values (" + FromClientID + "," + ToClient + ",'" + msg + "')";
        new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).Insert(query);
    }
}
```

the msg is sent to database as it is in it's without being replace what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: also, another thought: i would do the replacements after reading out of the database, not before writing to it. With the above method, you might get problems when, for example, the urls change. or you want to implement a new client, not running in a browser (nor even using html as the markup). Also, if you now add new smileys, they will only be applied to future messages, not to past ones.
just a thought though, the answer to your question is perfectly elaborated by jon skeet (what an honor :D )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're assuming that `Replace` modifies the existing* string. It doesn't. It returns a *new* string, with the modifications made. It has to, because strings are immutable in .NET. *All* string operations which you *might* expect to change the string (`Substring`, `ToUpper` etc) actually return a new one.

So all of your calls like this:

```
msg.Replace(...);
```

should probably be:

```
msg = msg.Replace(...);
```

You should *also* start using parameterized SQL instead of putting all your values directly into the SQL query. This will make your code more readable, avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and remove a lot of data type conversion issues.

Additionally, I'd use braces on every `if` statement, and put statements on separate lines:

```
if (msg.Contains(":-)"))
{
     msg = msg.Replace(":-)", "<img src='Styles/emojie/smile.png'   />  ");
}
```

Oh, and currently you'll only make *one* set of replacements in `msg` due to the `if / else` statements. Do you really not want to replace `:-(` if you've already replaced `:-)`? There's really no need to make the `Contains` check first... I'd just chain the calls together, unconditionally:

```
msg = msg.Replace(":-)", "<img src='Styles/emojie/smile.png'/> ")
         .Replace(":-(", "<img src='Styles/emojie/sad.png'/> ")
         .Replace(":'-(", "<img src='Styles/emojie/cry.png'/> ")
         .Replace(":-$", "<img src='Styles/emojie/shy.png'/> ");
```

Much simpler.

Comment: so if my msg is 'example:-)' it would be after replacement 'example<img src='smile.png' />' ??

Answer (score 1):

Calling `string.Replace` doesn't actually change the string, so you need to re-assign it:

```
msg = msg.Replace( ... );
```